# Change Reorder Control's color in table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, user-interface

In the image below, how do I change the color of the buttons on the right hand side of the view to white?**edit: Ideally only want it to be white for certain cells and black for others** Here's my code:

```
cell.backgroundColor = .appOrange
cell.contentLabel.textColor = .white
cell.numberLabel.textColor = .white
cell.tintColor = .white //this appears to do nothing, just something I tried
```

[image]

Comment: try changing global tintcColor to white, If the requirement of the whole app is white  tint color.

Comment: isnt this the accessoryView? Maybe there is something to set

Comment: Nah, it's not the accessoryView's tint color or the table view's tint color. I also don't want it to be white for every cell in the app. Ideally not even white for every cell in this table view

Comment: I think a good solution to your problem is to use two images (black image and white image) as the accessory view.

Comment: Is it a custom button in your cell?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works for me in my UITableViewController using iOS11 and Swift 4:

```
private var myReorderImage : UIImage? = nil;

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    for subViewA in cell.subviews {
        if (subViewA.classForCoder.description() == "UITableViewCellReorderControl") {
            for subViewB in subViewA.subviews {
                if (subViewB.isKind(of: UIImageView.classForCoder())) {
                    let imageView = subViewB as! UIImageView;
                    if (myReorderImage == nil) {
                        let myImage = imageView.image;
                        myReorderImage = myImage?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate);
                    }
                    imageView.image = myReorderImage;
                    imageView.tintColor = UIColor.red;
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still works with iOS 16 and Swift 6

Answer (score 20):

In iOS13.x seems like reorder control's color is dependent on the Light/Dark mode (earlier it was set on contrast with background, now it appears fixed depending on the mode).
Therefore there is a possibility to switch color of the reorder control by `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` of the UITableViewCell.

Default - in the light mode of the phone I get practically invisible controls:

[image: Default - in the light mode of the phone I get practically invisible controls]

Now applying

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...
    SelectableCell *cell = [tableView     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"selectableCell"];
    ...
    cell.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyleDark;

   return cell;
}
```

gives following result:

[image: Overriding - UI style]

Comment: For those of us who implement color schemes independent of light/dark mode (my app has had a dozen dark color schemes since iOS 5), Apple's shoddy implementation has been problematic. Eg, the checkmark accessory obeys tintColor; the disclosure indicator does not. I've been using a custom accessory view for disclosure but with this solution I'll be getting rid of it. I'm also using this solution for the reorder control. I test my cell bg color brightness and choose UIInterfaceStyleDark/Light appropriately so as to trick Apple into tinting the disclosure/reorder appropriately. Works great.

Comment: This works for me in Swift as well. You just have to adjust your color sets to be agnostic which is meh considering how easy the fix is.

Comment: This works in Xamarin.ios. just need to change to UpperCamelCase

Answer (score 15):

I use an extension to find the reorder control imageView.

```
extension UITableViewCell {

    var reorderControlImageView: UIImageView? {
        let reorderControl = self.subviews.first { view -> Bool in
            view.classForCoder.description() == "UITableViewCellReorderControl"
        }
        return reorderControl?.subviews.first { view -> Bool in
            view is UIImageView
        } as? UIImageView
    }
}
```

In willDisplay I update the tintColor of the image view.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.reorderControlImageView?.tint(color: Color.text.uiColor)
}
```

Setting a tint color with a UIImageView extension

```
extension UIImageView {

    func tint(color: UIColor) {
        self.image = self.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        self.tintColor = color
    }
}
```

Comment: answer i was looking for

Answer (score 9):

With inspiration from Thomas answer above, I found a solution that works for me.

Trying Thomas solution, I was faced with the problem, that it does not update the view for cells that are already displayed. Therefore I chose to overwrite the setEditing method on my custom cells instead.

```
private var myReorderImage: UIImage? = nil

override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    for subViewA in self.subviews {
        if (subViewA.classForCoder.description() == "UITableViewCellReorderControl") {
            for subViewB in subViewA.subviews {
                if (subViewB.isKind(of: UIImageView.classForCoder())) {
                    let imageView = subViewB as! UIImageView;
                    if (self.myReorderImage == nil) {
                        let myImage = imageView.image;
                        myReorderImage = myImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate);
                    }
                    imageView.image = self.myReorderImage;
                    imageView.tintColor = .red;
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

And just in case if anyone is going back in time, here's Objective-C version of mikkel-cortnum's answer:

```
@implementation TintedReorderedCell

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    for (UIView *subViewA in self.subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass(subViewA.class) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"]) {
            for (UIView *subViewB in subViewA.subviews) {
                if ([subViewB isKindOfClass:UIImageView.class]) {
                    UIImageView *imageView = ((UIImageView *)subViewB);
                    imageView.image = [imageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
                    imageView.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless something changes in Swift or someone else manages to dig up an answer, I researched this pretty well, and it looks like there isn't a way to do it without changing the `UIReorderControl` file, which will probably get your app rejected.

My solution is to implement the "long tap and drag," which there are tutorials on online. It's not ideal and not incredibly easy to implement unfortunately.