# Change color of the drag/move Knob in reorderable tableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cell

I have a `tableView` in editing-Mode for reordering Cells. I want to customize the color of the Knob for dragging the `Cell`. Actually, it is light grey. To understand what the picture is showing: I have a `Cell` with a height of 70, and a `uiview` with a height of 60 in it because I want more Space between the Cells. That's why you see the grey parts of the knob (yellow arrows). These I want to have in the same Background color as the `tableView` itself.

Maybe someone knows how I achieve this?

[image: Ugly TableViewCell]

Comment: see my answer in [Change Reorder Control's color in table view cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45967210/change-reorder-controls-color-in-table-view-cell/48819186#48819186)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... Got it. Using the Code from here [Change Reorder Control's color in table view cell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48819186/10155771) i modified it in this way:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    for subViewA in cell.subviews {
        if (subViewA.classForCoder.description() == "UITableViewCellReorderControl") {
            subViewA.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.89, green:0.00, blue:0.45, alpha:1.0)
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now it looks like i want:

[Nice looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ie1ZL.png)

Answer (score 0):

So far, I've no hint to how set its background color. However there is others options you want to explore to have this space between cells :

- Add extra "empty" cells between cells
- Add sections for each cells.

I'd go with the second option if I could afford it.

PS : Maybe you can a view under your tableview with the desired color.

Comment: I have found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45967210/change-reorder-controls-color-in-table-view-cell). It works party, but only changing the color of the "rows" in that knob. I also have investigate the "subviews" in that code, and it seems there are Images i could change programmatically. I already have Sections in that tableView, to add empty Cells to get Spaces is not a got way, i guess.

Comment: The first answer is : "I made it custom". Sure you can do the same.
The second is : "I use a private class silently and I hope my app won't get rejected"